# What is "dictionary-style string formatting" used in Django RedirectView url

Tags: django

I am familiar with using dictionaries in format strings, but I am confused by the term "dictionary-style string formatting" [as it is used in Django's docs for specifying the url in a RedirectView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView).

Specifically, I have one url: `r'^(?P<school_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<menu_type_slug>[\w-]+)/.pdf$'`  which I am deprecating and want to 301 (permanent) redirect to a new url   `r'^(?P<school_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<menu_type_slug>[\w-]+)/print/$'` and i'm wondering how to format the url argument to the RedirectView constructor so that the url kwargs will be utilized when constructing the new url to redirect to, but am not familiar with "dictionary-style string formatting".  What is the proper syntax to do this?

Comment: http://www.diveintopython.net/html_processing/dictionary_based_string_formatting.html

Comment: Thanks @Barmar.  I was familiar with that style of using dictionaries in format strings, I guess I wasn't putting two and two together and reconciling it with recapturing the regex url parameters.  Simple, now I see what they mean.

Comment: The key to making the link is the documentation's warning about `%` characters in the string needing to be doubled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That refers to a specific way to use the % string-formatting operator:

```
print "Hello, %(thing)s!" % {"thing": "world"}
```

prints "Hello, world!"

You want to use a redirect URL like '/%(school_slug)s/%(menu_type_slug)s/print/', the redirect view will receive a kwargs dictionary with keys 'school_slug' and 'menu_type_slug' and use it as argument for %.

Answer (score 1):

It refers to formatting strings by interpolating entries from a dictionary into a string:

```
>>> params = {"server":"mpilgrim", "database":"master", "uid":"sa", "pwd":"secret"}
>>> "%(pwd)s" % params                                    1
'secret'
```

If I interpret the Django documentation correctly, you can only use this to substitute URL query parameters, which are of the form `kwd=value`. The components of the path are not available for substitution.